# Checking for disconnect in P2P UDP C#

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, p2p

I'm making an application in which three users get into a session and send each other UDP data (Peer to Peer). How can I detect if one of the users has disconnected from the session?

Comment: Please explain the type of connection.  You cannot have multiple users connect on a single Peer To Peer.

Answer (score 0):

Because UDP is not connection based, the only way to tell if a user has disconnected is to check if you are no longer receiving responses or messages from them.

One strategy is to have users send 'heartbeat' messages periodically and track if a user has missed the last X number of heartbeats in a row, and at that point assume they are disconnected. These messages don't need to contain any information, just receiving them is what's important.

You should also have users send a "disconnection message" when they disconnect, but **do not** rely solely on this, as the user may crash or the message may otherwise get lost and never be received.

Comment: Udp can either be broadcast or connection based.  Nick is wrong.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol "UDP uses a simple connectionless communication model"

Comment: Broadcast is the most common method for UDP.  But you can still use UDP exactly like TCP without the acknowlegement.

Comment: UDP is a connection-less protocol by definition. I think you're confused about something.

Comment: For instance, even if you use "Connect" with a udpclient, it doesn't actually establish a connection. It's more like establishing a filter.

Comment: Nick : I know what I'm talking about.  There is no difference between the connection for TCP and UDP.  The only difference between the two is the protocol that TCP sends an ACK.  UDPs allow for BROADCast option where there is no one-to-one connection, but still can have a one-to-one.